# python2.7.11 prints "?25l[?25h[" for base64 module

Tags: python

Can someone please help to understand why im getting extra `?23[` character in the output. Running python 2.7.11 on Mac

```
 import base64

    original_string = '?25l['
    print 'Original:', original_string

    encoded_string = base64.b32encode(original_string)
    print 'Encoded :', encoded_string

    decoded_string = base64.b32decode(encoded_string)
    print 'Decoded :', decoded_string
```

my output is :

```
Original: ?25lOriginal: ?25l[
Encoded : H4ZDK3A3LM======
Decoded : ?25lDecoded : ?25l[

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I would expect something like that :

```
Original: ?25l[
Encoded : H4ZDK3A3LM===
Decoded : ?25l[
```

Comment: Neither of `H4ZDK3A3LM======` and `H4ZDK3A3LM===` is valid as general base64 encoded value, but that could be Python specific encoding.

Comment: Can you fix the indent in your sample to make it runnable code? When I fixed the indenting and ran your script I got the expected output (except that the encoded string was H4ZDK3C3) not the output you claim. Is this really the code you are running? I'm running python 2.7.6 on linux mint.

Comment: You may want to change your title... you are doing `base32` encoding not `base64`.

Comment: When I decode `'H4ZDK3A3LM======'` I get `'?25l\x1b['` which appears to be a messed up ANSI terminal control code. For instance, `'\x1b[?25l'` turns off the cursor. If you print that string in python in a terminal window, it will turn the cursor off. For everybody who just did that,  `'\x1b[?25h'` turns the cursor back on again. It seems you have some pretty printer or menu maker that has gotten out of sequence and is throwing messed up escape codes out. So, (1) you aren't really dealing with "?25l[" (there is an escape in there) and (2) this isn't really the code causing the problem.

Comment: thank you @tdelaney ..."pretty printer" or "menu maker" I don't think I use any of these. Unless you can please share more details.

Comment: Just speculation. Try this. Copy/paste your example to a .py file and run it from a terminal window. You'll find it has indentation errors. Fix that (and also edit your question to fix it) and it should print the stuff that you expect. It worked properly for me. Does it work for you? The stuff that prints oddly for you looks suspiciously like broken terminal escape sequences used to colorize or otherwise fancy up a display. For instance, running this with ipython would add these extra sequences.

Comment: @tdelaney  the thing its not related to the terminal I'm guessing .  I tried it in multiple terminals ( iTerm2, teminalMac, pycharm) , my ~/.bash_profile has no fancy settings ( actually tried to delete  it ot test this) but still getting those errors if I'm running e. g. : `python above_example.py > test.txt `, and after checking the `open test.txt ` with mac default text vier or sublime I can see  this esc charaters .

Comment: When I run your script I get `IndentationError: unexpected indent`. When I decode `'H4ZDK3A3LM======'` I get `'?25l\x1b['`, not `'?25l['`. Not sure what else to say!